# Disabled the input field after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, codeigniter

[image]

_this is my UI

```
<script>
    function changeTextbox()
    {
        $("#service_request").on("change", function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Group Code")
        {
        $("#employee_id").attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
         $("#employee_id").removeAttr("disabled");
       }

  });
}
```

_that is my script

```
<select style="width:199px;border-radius:10px;" id="service_request" name="service_request" class="form-control" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

    <option value="Default Request" selected disabled>Default Request Service</option>
        <?php if(isset($records)): foreach($records as $row):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->service_group;?>"><?php echo $row->service_group;?></option>                                
            <?php endforeach;?>                     
            <?php else:?>
                <p>Request Service not available</p>
            <?php endif;?>
```

_this is how my select options goes

```
 <input style="border-radius:10px;width:425px;height:35px;" type="text" id="employee_id"  name="assign_to" onkeyup="autocomplet()" placeholder="Approver" onchange="changeTextbox()"/>
```

_this is for my input text field

[image]
_its the value in my inspect element

**
_I don't know what's going on with this code, the Approver text field should be disabled, if the Group Code service is selected, but it turn's out to be not working, someone help me please :D**

Comment: Remove `onchange="changeTextbox()` and `function changeTextbox()
    {}`, just keep function body and try...

Comment: `employee_id` is  unique in DOM? show us html code for name input

Comment: @Rayon _ still not working

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are you sure id `employee_id ` is unique ?

Comment: @Rayon
_is it possible to run in JSFiddle ? sorry I haven't  tried it yet
.I am using codeigniter framework, then its datum are stored in database with stored procedures, then to server
.it's a bit complicated
.I don't think so if I can shared an executable demo/snippet. :(

Comment: @cske 
_yes it is unique
.here's the html code for name input

 <label> Name</label>
    <?php if(isset($user)): foreach($user as $row):?>
    <input style="border-radius:10px;width:425px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>&nbsp;<?php echo $row->last_name;?>" readonly="readonly"  required>
    <?php endforeach;?>
           
        <?php else:?>
        <p>Name not available</p>
        <?php endif;?>
   </div>

Comment: @Ravikirankalal
_yes I'm sure it's unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textbox disabled property is dependent on select change event so onchange for textbox is useless so remove the function `changeTextbox()` . In your script on select change event do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#service_request').on('change',function(){

    if($(this).val() == 'Group Code' )
        //$("#employee_id").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
          $("#employee_id").prop("disabled", true); 
    else
        //$("#employee_id").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#employee_id").prop("disabled", false); 
    });
});
```

Comment: change 'service_request' to '#service_request' to make it working :)

Comment: _thanks @mhasan
.just really a simple error, I just don't put $(document).ready............ :D
.many thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, when you change the select.

```
$(document).on("change","#service_request", function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Group Code")
        {
           $("#employee_id").attr("disabled","disabled");
        } 
        else 
        {
           $("#employee_id").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
}
```

You can also use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

By using removeAttr(), you are completely removing the disabled attribute itself - while prop() is merely setting the property's underlying boolean value to false.

```
$('#employee_id').prop("disabled", true);
$('#employee_id').prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: change #elementID to #employee_id :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the on `change` event listener the using the `disabled` attr

```
let opt = document.querySelector("select");
let input = document.querySelector("input");
opt.addEventListener("change",function(){

    input.disabled = true;

});
```

http://jsbin.com/mugina/1/edit?html,js,output